# Using string variables within a formula in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I do not understand why this code doesn't work:

```
Cells(i, formula_col_index).Value = "=IF(" & time_location & "<>" & time_benchmark & ",""ERROR"",""OK"")"
```

where

```
time_location=" 17:00:00",
time_benchmark=" 17:30:00"
```

It keeps throwing application-defined (or object-defined) error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what doesnt work?

Comment: Yep, it is an application-defined or object-defined error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your variables `time_location` and `time_benchmark` contains string values, you should include them in double quotes when using formula:

```
Cells(i, formula_col_index).Value = "=IF(""" & time_location & """<>""" & time_benchmark & """,""ERROR"",""OK"")"
```

Comment: omg im not thinking straight today..  haha I have ran out of votes but a definite +1 and -1 for me being a complete idiot on this one